# Group N indistinguishable balls into 3 jars of different capacity

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have a problem that can be phrased like follows. How many ways can we group $N$ indistinguishable balls into three jars, given the (different) capacity of each jar.

Let the total capacity of all 3 jars be $M$ balls. The number of balls is $N$ so that $0\leq N\leq M$.

For example, let the capacities be $[1,3,4]$ giving $M=1+3+4=7$ and lets put $N=4$. Then we get the following $8$ possible solutions (the rows):

```
1 3 0
1 2 1
1 1 2
1 0 3
0 3 1
0 2 2
0 1 3
0 0 4
```

As is clear, the jars may be empty. As long as the the number of balls is smaller than then the capacity of the smallest jar, the number of solutions follow the third diagonal of pascals triangle $1, 3, 6, 10, 15, ...$. For the example jar-set above the number of distributions for different numbers of balls $N = 0, 1, 2, ... M$ is:

```
1  3  5  7  8  7  5  3  1
```

Increasing the capacities to e.g. $[7,3,6]$ we have for $N = 0, 1, 2, ... M$

```
1  3  6 10 14 18 22 25 26 25 22 18 14 10  6  3  1
```

I've been able to generate the solutions and count them, giving these numbers, but would like to see a closed form expression. Some extra insight/trivia is also welcome.

PS. I can find many similar questions but not with different box/jar sizes.

Comment: I don't immediately know the answer, so take the comment with a grain of salt, but I would personally recommend first looking at the case where two jars are given with this property, instead of three, and assume $M$ balls are to be distributed. Go through the cases for the jar of capacity $M_1$ that still allow the second jar of capacity $M_2=M-M_1$ to fill, using stars and bars and summing over all possibilities. Then see if you can use this result to generalize to three jars, as this would just be breaking down $M_1$ to the same problem again, so to speak.

Comment: I guess $1+3+4 \ne 7$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $m_i$ $(1\leq i\leq3)$ be the capacities of the jars. Then the number $n$ you are looking for is the coefficient of $x^N$ in the polynomial 
$$p(x):=(1+x+x^2+\ldots+ x^{m_1})(1+\ldots+x^{m_2})(1+x+\ldots+ x^{m_3})\ .$$
Write $p(x)$ as
$$\eqalign{p(x)&={1-x^{m_1+1}\over 1-x}{1-x^{m_2+1}\over 1-x}{1-x^{m_3+1}\over 1-x}\cr&=(1-x^{m_1+1})(1-x^{m_2+1})(1-x^{m_3+1})\sum_{k=0}^\infty{-3\choose k}(-x)^k\cr &=(1-x^{m_1+1})(1-x^{m_2+1})(1-x^{m_3+1})\sum_{k=0}^\infty{k+2\choose 2}x^k\ .\cr}$$
The product of the first three factors on the RHS has (depending on the $m_i$) at most $8$ terms of degree $\leq N$, all of them with coefficient $\pm1$. Pair each of these terms $\pm x^\ell$ with the  factor ${k+2\choose2}x^k={1\over2}(k+1)(k+2)x^k$ such that $k+\ell=N$, and add up.

Comment: Is there a way to get a closed form for the coefficient of x^k in product of 3 terms on the RHS?

Comment: Thanks a lot Christian. This gives a lot of insight, so I marked it green. I managed to get around the problem by finally realizing that instead of generating the solutions for a given M, one can/should exhaust all solutions for M=0,1,...,Mmax  using a tripple loop over 0..m1, 0..m2, 0..m3, which will generate (m1+1)(m2+1)(m3+1) solutions in total, and then the numbers I originally asked for are not needed.